# SQLAlchemy. Show tables in existing schema

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I want to read a table from SQL Server using SQLAlchemy. This table already exists and has primary key. However, it's located in the schema 'my_schema'. And I can't reach this table.

On the contrary, using the following code I can reach a table from another database, which does not have schemas:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, String, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
no_schema_engine = create_engine(
"firebird+fdb://%(user)s:%(pwd)s@%(host)s:%(port)d/%(path)s?charset=%(charset)s" % insert_params,
encoding=insert_params['charset']) 
metadata = MetaData()  
my_table= Table('my_table_name',metadata, Column('id', String, primary_key=True), autoload=True, autoload_with=no_schema_engine )
session = Session(no_schema_engine)
sample_row = session.query(my_table).first()
print(sample_row)
>> (1, datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 8, 22, 58, 23, 947000))
```

When I change the engine to connect to SQL Server and to copy the same table (but now it has schema), it throws an error `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: my_table_name`.
I use the same code as above, except I change the engine and the row

```
my_table= Table('my_table_name',metadata, Column('id', String, primary_key=True), autoload=True, autoload_with=schema_engine, schema='my_schema')
```

It's also important to note that SQLAlchemy actually can see all the schemas in SQL Server database but can't see tables:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
inspector = inspect(source_engine)
print(inspector.get_table_names())
>> []
schemas = inspector.get_schema_names()
print(schemas)
>> ['my_schema_1', 'my_schema_2', ...]
```

Comment: What do you see if you `print(inspector.get_table_names(schema="my_schema"))` ?

Comment: @GordThompson, The output is  `[] `

Comment: What about `print({x: inspector.get_table_names(schema=x) for x in inspector.get_schema_names()})` ? That should print all table names for all schemas.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for your time  and help. The problem was not trivial. I've solved it. The thing is that SQLAlchemy works with information_schema. To use the approach with ```Table()``` we need an access to this information_schema of the selected database. In my case I had rigths to read tables from this database with pandas, but I didn't have the right to see information_schema. Our database administrator fixed that and now can read tables to the ```Table```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I'm connecting to a SQL Server and manipulating with SQLAlchemy.

Tables with schema "dbo" were retrieving with method `get_table_names()`. Notice that 'dbo' is the default schema. Tables with other schema were not retrieved. I needed to specify the schema name as a parameter in the method (`get_table_names(schema=schema_name)`.

I reproduce the steps that I use for retrieving my table names from SQL Server:

```py
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

# Params are defined in my environment
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    f"DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD};Trusted_Connection=yes;"

# Create URL with the params
url = "mssql+pyodbc://?odbc_connect={}".format(params)

# Create an Engine
engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)

# Create an inspector
inspector = inspect(engine)

# Retrieve tables with schema 'dbo'

tables_dbo = inspector.get_table_names()

# Retrieve tables with other schema
schema_name = "other_schema"
tables_other_schema = inspector.get_table_names(schema=schema_name)
```

As I can check from your examples, you could get your schema names and then loop the list to get the table names in each schema.

```py
# Get schema names
schema_names = inspector.get_schema_names()
table_names = []

# Add tables names to a list
for schema in schema_names:
    table_names += inspector.get_table_names(schema=schema)

print(table_names)
```